# Groovy for Rubyists - #each_slice

Tags: ruby, groovy

In ruby I have #each_slice...

```
(1..10).each_slice(3).to_a
=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]
```

I'm looking for an elegant way to do the same in Groovy and this is all I got so far as a beginner:

```
arr = []
list = (1..10) as Queue
while(!list.isEmpty()) {
sub_arr = []
3.times { sub_arr << list.poll() }
    sub_arr.removeAll([null])
    arr << sub_arr
}
arr
Result: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `collate` in groovy

```
(1..10).collate(3)
```